# Math operations with NULL in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why

```
select 1 - NULL
```

returns NULL instead of 1?

It wasn't clearly expected to me.

Comment: because sir,,`NULL` is not `0`...

Comment: If you want to replace NULL as 0 in your query, then you can use function `ISNULL()`, e.g. `SELECT 1 - ISNULL(column_name, 0)`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null: A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.

If you do any arithmetic operations with null the whole expression evaluates to Null. In order to handle null you should use Isnull() or coalesce function like this.

```
select 1 - isnull(NULL,0) as result
```

Comment: Yeah, I did exactly that you're suggesting. But that was a bit confusing to me. I expected NULL ignoring like aggregation functions do.

Comment: Built in functions would ignore nulls implicitly but in your case you should explicitly mention how to handle null to SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

Simply because `NULL` is not `0`.

If it helps, consider `NULL` as a synonym for "unknown", and then it'll make perfect sense - the result of 1 minus an unknown number can only give an unknown result.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that it's also true when concatenating strings - i.e `'Rowland' + NULL + 'Shaw'` will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some references on how `NULL` behaves differently:

- `NULL` can be thought of as UNKNOWN ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql)).
- Arithmetic operations with `NULL` result in `NULL` ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Arithmetic_operations)).
- `SUM()` operation ignores `NULL` instead of returning UNKNOWN ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql)).
- String concatenation with `NULL` result in `NULL` ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#String_concatenation) and [comment by @Zohar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38179284/5301903)).
- Boolean comparisons with `NULL` use three-value logic ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_(3VL))).
- Where clauses with `NULL` should use `IS`, because boolean comparisons result in UNKNOWN not `TRUE` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql#Remarks)).

> To determine whether an expression is NULL, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL instead of comparison operators (such as = or !=). Comparison operators return UNKNOWN when either or both arguments are NULL.